# Generalization of a Hadamard matrix

Tags: combinatorics, matrices

As a generalization of a Hadamard matrix, a c-matrix is a square matrix with one entry 0 and all other entries -1 or 1 in each row. With each row being pairwise orthogonal. Show that the transpose of a c-matrix is a c-matrix.

I can visualize why this true but I'm not sure how to go about proving this.

Answer (score 1):

You can turn the matrix into an orthogonal matrix by normalizing rows appropriately.  Then argue from there...